# How do I change the default colors in snowsql cli?

Tags: snowsql

I'm using Windows putty with a colour scheme that works well for all of my work. In this case, I'm connecting to a unix o/s. The colours work fine in snowsql, except display of NULL values. I can't find ANY colours that work with snowsql's display of NULL. Here's the plain text example:

```
<obfuscated>:SYSADMIN#@<obfuscated>.(no schema)> select NULL;
select NULL;
NULL
NULL
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.082s
```

... and here's my screen in colour ...
[image]

You see my snowsql prompt with the statement in green. Then the echo of that statement (echo=True). Then the 'header' of the result table with NULL. And if you look REALLY CLOSELY, you will see the content of the result value, "NULL" is in a very difficult to see colour!

None of the snowsql options for output_format=xxxx work for this.

The colors only "live inside" of the snowsql cli, so it probably needs to be a colour scheme fix. So perhaps solving the specific example of NULL would answer the larger scope of my question. Possibly relevant to this problem, I noticed the option **syntax_style** only has 1 value right now. So perhaps the answer is "... in a future release..." ;-)

Comment: @Taisuke put me on a good path. Snowsql uses colorama, and colorama uses standard ASCII colour sequences. I've determined that the NULL values are using the ANSI Bold Black escape sequence. My terminal s/w, putty, allows me to define this as a different actual RGB display value. Still no direct snowsql solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also hit by this issue - snowsql CLI seems to use wide range of colors ranging from yellow to black, so some part of its ouput is always nearly invisible regardless of color scheme setting. Also changing TERM environment variable does not seem to help.

However, I noticed snowsql output is in acceptable color set when I use TeraTerm as my terminal. I usually use Cmder/ConEmu, and in that case, no color scheme setting helped.
Also disabling support for escape sequence related to color improved the result, though I only get black/white output in that case.

So I guess your best bet is to try changing your terminal software to something else.
If your terminal can switch/disable supported escape sequence set, that might help as well.